# Does Feng Shui have an impact on User Experience?

Tags: design, feng-shui

Being a part of the digital world since the beginning of internet, I’ve seen many different web design techniques, from the obviously scary example from [Lings Cars](http://www.lingscars.com/)...

[image]

. . . to web designs that enforces simplicity and gives a clam impression such as [Web Design Feng Shui (DE)](http://www.webdesign-fengshui.de/).

[image]

It’s obvious why one of the two is closer to what we do, than the other.

[Feng Shui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feng_shui) is, according to Wikipedia:

> a Chinese philosophical system of harmonizing everyone with the surrounding environment. The term feng shui literally translates as "wind-water" in English. This is a cultural shorthand taken from the passage of the now-lost Classic of Burial recorded in Guo Pu's commentary. Feng shui is one of the Five Arts of Chinese Metaphysics, classified as physiognomy (observation of appearances through formulas and calculations). The feng shui practice discusses architecture in metaphoric terms of "invisible forces" that bind the universe, earth, and humanity together, known as qi.

The simple first phrase *“harmonizing everyone with the surrounding environment”*, sound very much like User Experience. Therefore, I wonder if there is there something, we can learn from Feng Shui even though its original aim is physical and not digital. Searching for ["feng shui" + "web design"](https://www.google.se/search?q=%22feng%20shui%22%20%2B%20%22web%20design%22&oq=%22feng%20shui%22%20%2B%20%22web%20design%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.146j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) gives roughly 450k hits, with a lot of guides, best practices and templates to use for various frameworks. **Does Feng Shui have an impact on User Experience**, or are they not related at all.

Comment: Lings Cars design is very much intentional. It might look a hideous mess, but that is on purpose (and it's surprisingly well put together too). It's almost part of her brand that the site is like that. A clean, neat, generic site would potentially harm that brand, believe it or not.

Comment: @JonW I know. I've tweeted with them a few years ago and it is intentional and funny too. It's fun to see someone not trying to use "less is more". And they stand out from the crowd, which is very conscious.

Comment: Exactly. It's an interesting marketing technique, but it clearly works. I mean how many other car leasing companies in the UK can you name off the top of your head?

Comment: I remember owner of Lings Cars went on BBC's Dragons' Den

Comment: http://www.arngren.net/ :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's just assume for a moment that Feng Shui has some sort of real benefit—at least for the first part of this post.

### Assuming Feng Shui is true

Feng Shui is all about the orientation of various elements relative to various fixed spatial compass points and celestial bodies.  So having something face East is supposed to have a different energy flow than having that same thing face West.  Or having a doorway face the rising sun is different from facing the setting sun.

The problem here is that the moment you enter the digital world, all spacial orientation really loses consistency.  Will the UX only be good if I orient my tablet 23° East?  Clearly not, so we can strike one off for the digital world.

So what about UX in a non-digital spatially oriented world?  That leads nicely to the second section...

### Feng Shui is silly

A number of blind tests have been done where acknowledged Feng Shui experts were independently asked to assess a house.  Surprise, surprise...they came back with contradictory advice and assessments.  Feng Shui is clearly subjective no matter how much its' proponents refer to it as a science.  So, you can't really "make something Feng Shui" even if you wanted to.

### Marketing

That being said, many people with money buy into Feng Shui, just like many people with money buy into horoscopes.  If your particular user base need something to be Feng Shui, then doing what is necessary for them to "feel the Feng Shui" is a good UX tactic, simply because they believe it's true.  Placebos work if you believe they do.

Comment: +1 for "Feng Shui is silly" section. Exactly where I was going to go.